MySQL counts the rows of some tables wrong
This statement run in MySQL (8.3.0)
SELECT 
    TABLE_NAME AS `Table Name`, 
    table_rows AS `Total Rows`, 
    ROUND((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024, 2) AS `Table Size (MB)`
FROM 
    information_schema.tables
WHERE 
    table_schema = 'my_db'
ORDER BY 
    TABLE_NAME ASC
;

should display all tables of the database my_db with the names, rows, and sizes.
I run it on a DB with about 30GB. In the result table some tables (about the halft of all tables: from the middle downwards to the end) seem to have 0 rows. And that's definitely wrong. They do have rows.
What is happening?

You have tagged your question with statistics. Statistics are not always updated in real time, and the manual says as much about the information_schema.tables.table_rows:

Some storage engines, such as MyISAM, store the exact count. For other storage engines, such as InnoDB, this value is an approximation, and may vary from the actual value by as much as 40% to 50%.

So

use SELECT COUNT(*) to obtain an accurate count


Databases are dynamic beasts in which things are changing all the time.
The Statistics are the database's "best guess".  Keeping exact track of every record would be an expensive, and potentially disruptive, operation, affected by transactions and the like.  Periodically taking a "rough measurement" is a necessary compromise.

Please provide data_length and index_length for some table erroneously showing 0.00.
